# How do I load 2 flask apps to serve 2 subdomains for nginx/uwsgi using unix sockets?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, webfaction

I am following [this uwsgi guide](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#virtual-hosting) to setting up `nginx/uwsgi` to have 1 flask app run the "www" subdomain and another flask app to run the "api" subdomain. My `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /path/to/access_nginx.log combined;
    error_log   /path/to/error_nginx.log  crit;

    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    server {
    server_name   api.example.com;
        listen 14265;

        location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi_api;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///path/to/api.sock;
        }
    }

    server {
    server_name   www.example.com;
        listen 14265;

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///path/to/wsgi.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

For starting uwsgi, I do:

```
#!/bin/bash
APPNAME=nginx
# Start uwsgi
${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/bin/uwsgi \
  --uwsgi-socket "${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/wsgi.sock" \
  --master \
  --workers 1 \
  --max-requests 10000 \
  --harakiri 60 \
  --daemonize ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/uwsgi.log \
  --pidfile ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/uwsgi.pid \
  --vacuum \
  --python-path ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}

# Start nginx
${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/bin/nginx
```

When I visit `www.example.com` it works as expected. However, I get a 502 error for `api.example.com`. To fix the 502 error I can change `api.sock` to `wsgi.sock` in my `nginx.conf` but it will give me the page for `www.example.com` when I visit `api.example.com` (even though `wsgi.py` and `wsgi_api.py` are different).

EDIT: The examples I have found for setting up multiple subdomains on nginx/uwsgi (including the one I linked to) all show how to do subdomains with static sites. I cannot find one that shows how to do it with unix sockets.

Comment: Your nginx config is fine. Response code "502 Bad Gateway" means that something wrong with uWSGI. Check the log of api application.

Comment: @DmitryVakhrushev I've checked that. Each app works fine on it's own but when I try the above configuration then I get a 502 error on one. I've also noticed that only wsgi.sock gets created, which suggests my uwsgi configuration is wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also noticed that only wsgi.sock gets created

That is the answer of your question, if you didn't get `api.sock` nginx will not be able to pass query to it. So you will get 502. You should start `uwsgi` for each of your apps:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start uwsgi 
for APPNAME in "app_1" "app_2"
do
    uwsgi \
      --uwsgi-socket "${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/wsgi.sock" \
      --master \
      --workers 1 \
      --max-requests 10000 \
      --harakiri 60 \
      --daemonize ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/uwsgi.log \
      --pidfile ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}/uwsgi.pid \
      --vacuum \
      --python-path ${HOME}/webapps/${APPNAME}
done
```